# HTML checkbox CSS: Cursor default or pointer?

Tags: html, css

Is there a definitive standard for the cursor on an HTML checkbox?

Default, pointer, or (shudder) text?

Comment: If you don't style it, what does it look like? Looks rather `default`ish to me. But if you just never style it, the user agent can choose how it wants to display it. And so I fail to really see what this question is about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [CSS Cursor Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp), it appears that the default setting for `cursor` is `auto` and it lets the browser decide what is to be displayed when a user interacts with a checkbox. I guess there would be a "definitive standard" for each browser, so I guess there  really isn't a standard? Do whatever you'd like while keeping it reasonable (no text cursors, please!)

Most checkboxes that I come across use the default cursor (but maybe that's due to my use of Google Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what is your definition of "Definitive standard". Default is default, which means without any modification, the look will be shown with default settings (pointer).

Answer (score 1):

In the web world, no standard exist. Even W3C never issues **standards**, but **recommendations**. Therefore, whatever you like to do, you're free to do. But there are some **guidelines**, **conventions**, and **recommendations** which is better to be followed, if you want to conform to the cummunity.